# Rsyslog - logs not displayed on server

Tags: logging, centos, firewall, syslog, rsyslog

Trying to configure [Rsyslog](https://www.rsyslog.com/) Client to Send Logs to Rsyslog Server.

Both machines run on Centos7 with [Vagrant](https://app.vagrantup.com/centos/boxes/7).

See configuration of each machine below.

When I log inside the Client machine - It is not reflected on the server's logs.

For example:

```
logger "Some message..."
```

But when I add the server's IP to the command:

```
logger -n 192.168.11.11 "Some message..."
```

I can see that a directory with the Client's IP is being created on the Server machine:

```
[root@server log]# ls -la
total 200
drwxr-xr-x. 11 root   root     4096 Aug  1 12:02 .
drwxr-xr-x. 18 root   root      254 Jul 31 21:39 ..
drwx------.  2 root   root       25 Jul 31 22:18 192.168.11.22 <--- HERE
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root   root      191 Feb 28 20:54 anaconda
drwx------.  2 root   root       23 Jul 31 21:39 audit
-rw-------.  1 root   utmp        0 Aug  1 03:14 btmp
drwxr-xr-x.  2 chrony chrony      6 Apr 12  2018 chrony
-rw-------.  1 root   root      188 Jul 31 21:39 cron
-rw-r--r--.  1 root   root    26911 Aug  1 12:02 dmesg
-rw-r--r--.  1 root   root    26742 Jul 31 21:39 dmesg.old
-rw-r--r--.  1 root   root      374 Jul 31 21:47 firewalld
-rw-r--r--.  1 root   root   292292 Aug  1 12:12 lastlog
-rw-------.  1 root   root      198 Jul 31 21:39 maillog
.......
.......
```

And inside of it there is a `vagrant.log` file where I can see the log message for the Client:

```
2019-08-01T13:00:06+00:00 192.168.11.22 vagrant: Some message...
```

**Question: Any Idea why I can't see the Client local logs?**

For this discussion:

1. SELINUX is disabled.
2. [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280697/rsyslog-not-forwarding-messages-to-remote-rsyslog-server?rq=1) didn't helped.

---

### Rsyslog Configuration

Server IP: `192.168.11.11`.
Client IP: `192.168.11.22`.

Both machines have rsyslog installed & enabled and have the following **common** setup in the `/etc/rsyslog.conf` file:

```
#### MODULES ####    
$ModLoad imuxsock 
$ModLoad imjournal

#Open port 514 For UDP    
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514

#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####
$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
$OmitLocalLogging on
$IMJournalStateFile imjournal.state

#### RULES ####
kern.*                                       /dev/console    
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none     /var/log/messages
authpriv.*                                   /var/log/secure    
local7.*                                     /var/log/boot.log
```

**Additions for each machine on the** `/etc/rsyslog.conf` file.

On the **Server** machine:

```
## Rules for processing remote logs 
 $template RemoteLogs,"/var/log/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log" 
 *.* ?RemoteLogs 
 & ~
```

On the **Client** machine I Setup UDP Forwarding to the Server's IP:

```
# ### begin forwarding rule ###
#UDP Forwarding
*. * @192.168.11.11:514 
# ### end of the forwarding rule ###
```

---

### Firewall Configuration

On the **Server** machine - Opening port 514 on firewall:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=514/udp
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

And Verifying:

```
[root@server /]#  sudo ss -tulnp | grep "rsyslog"

udp    UNCONN     0   0     *:514  *:*   users:(("rsyslogd",pid=2711,fd=3))
udp    UNCONN     0   0    :::514  :::*  users:(("rsyslogd",pid=2711,fd=4))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove one blank after `*.` on the client's host:
`*. * @192.168.11.11:514`

Default format for sending logs having any level on remote host looks like:
`*.* @remote-host:514`

Then restart rsyslog service on client and server with `systemctl restart rsyslog` and check again.

---

EDIT:

Pasted From the comments - 2 more steps that where done on the syslog server that solved the issue:

1. Commenting the `#### Rules ####` section on server.
2. The Removal of `& ~` from the `## Rules for processing remote logs` section.

Comment: @Rotemya Please, check, if there events from client on the server's local logs?  

Some following tips may be helpful:  
1.be sure that last string of config files is blank.  
2.on server's config: comment out string `& ~` and check.  
3.on server's config: try paste local rules after the rules for processing remote logs.

Comment: Thanks @Alexey: About "are there events from client on the server's local logs?" Not that I see, can you specify which folder to 'tail'?            $ ~ was removed. 
     About the placement of the remote rules - in my configuration (specified in the question) The section of ## Rules for processing remote logs as placed in ther server's rsyslog.conf file BEFORE the GLOBAL DIRECTIVES and RULES sections.

Comment: You can try these steps: 1) for correct resolving names add records in `/etc/hosts` on your hosts and check with `ping` 2) place section `Rules for processing remote log` after section `GLOBAL DIRECTIVES` and comment out section `Rules` 2) restart server's service with `systemctl restart rsyslog` 3) on client's config specify this: `*.info @192.168.11.11:514 ` 4) restart client's service with `systemctl restart rsyslog` 5) check folder `/var/log` on server, if there folder having dns-name of client (not ip), there may be  `systemd.log`, `rsyslog.log`, which client has sent.

Comment: Thank you @Alexey. From all your instructions the following should be placed as an answer: 1. Commenting Rules section on server. 2. The Removal of the & ~. Can you add it to your answer?

Comment: @Rotemya, Glad it helped. Just wanted to ask, are you looking now updates on logs are generated by server ?

Comment: I hope I understood you correctly. I saw the relevant logs under the <hostname> directory (daemon.log ,user.log, sudo.log ,logind.log, ssh.log) on the syslog server machine.

Answer (score 1):

Credit to @Alexey that helped me in two critical points.

I'll also add a few more useful points that might be helpful for others:

1: First of all, check the connectivity of the two machines. 
For example, if using vagrant networking, place the two machines in a network mode that they can see (ping) each other. For example Host-only mode is OK, but internal mode where each machine is on its isolated network - will not work.

2: Uncommenting the following code is required only in the syslog server:

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
```

3: On the client machine - you can comment the all `#### Rules ####` section and place the forwarding rule at the end of file **OR** 
you can specify the forwarding inline (with the client IP or hostname, if configured in `/etc/hosts`):

```
#### RULES ####
kern.*                                       /dev/console    
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none     @192.168.11.11:514 # <--- Like this
auth,authpriv.*                              /var/log/secure    
local7.*                                     /var/log/boot.log
```

4: A quick check to see if the UDP connection succeed:

Forward auth logs to server (like this `auth,authpriv.*  @192.168.11.11:514`).

ssh into the client machine, switch between users and view the following files under /var/log/ directory on server:

```
sshd.log  su.log  sudo.log  systemd-logind.log
```

5: Be careful with the rsyslog syntax - For example, If you're using [sed](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sed-command-in-linux-unix-with-examples/) as part of a provision script in order to replace and edit lines in the config file - check the output:

Specifying the $template section in one line:

```
$template RemoteLogs,"/var/log/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log" *.* ?RemoteLogs
```

Will lead to an error:

> Aug 03 13:50:04 server rsyslogd[5539]: error: extra characters in
>   config line ignored: '*.* ?RemoteLogs' [v8.24.0-34.el7]

This is the correct syntax - break rule into a new line (if generated with `sed` - just add `/n`):

```
$template RemoteLogs,"/var/log/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log" 
*.* ?RemoteLogs
```

6: Don't forget the `systemctl restart rsyslog` after each change in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`. Because of cases like #5 always check the rsyslog status: `systemctl status rsyslog`.

7: Newer versions of rsyslog (I think 5+) support a much cleaner syntax - it comes now as default on newer versions of Ubuntu for example, but for some reason not on Centos7.

8: On the syslog-server - Make sure your firewall is enabled and configured to accept UDP on relevant port (see configuration script in Question):

```
Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:syslog ctstate NEW
```